# Can't scroll anymore on touchstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchstart, touchmove

I want to add `touchstart` event on my `li` without disabling scroll on the parent.

Currently, it works. I have the scroll on `timeline` and I can click on `li`.

When I add `touchstart`, I can click one of the `li`, it's better than `click` on a mobile. **But the problem is, I can't scroll anymore on `timeline`...**

Can I differentiate touchstart, long press, touchmove or something like that ?

```
<ul id="timeline">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  ...
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

$("#timeline").find(" > li").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
});
```

I would like to use :

```
$("#timeline").find(" > li").on("touchstart click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [jQuery touchSwipe plugin](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/).

It lets you detect whether it was a long touch or a short touch which could solve the problem for you.

E.g.:

```
$(function() {  

    $("#timeline").find(" > li").swipe( {
        longTap:function(event, target) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // further code
        },
        allowPageScroll: "auto"
    });

});
```

Further you can enable page scrolling and define how it's handled:

[Page scrolling demo](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Page_scrolling.html)